# Error in dapp developed using 'Truffle' framework -Smart contract function call won't get executed

Tags: contract-design, truffle, testrpc, oracles, embark

I am developing a dapp using 'testrpc' and 'truffle'.I have also used ethereum-bridge for Oraclize.I have written a smart contract function which calls a url using 'OraclizeQuery'.

The following is the contract code :-

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

import "./usingOraclize.sol";
contract WeatherApiCall is usingOraclize {
       string public weathercondition;
       uint public personscount=2;
       function WeatherApiCall() { 
            OAR = OraclizeAddrResolverI(0xec6487ae821eb3c874c197067ad134faa99c3c11);//contractaddress retrieved on to deploying the Oraclize OAR and Connector from ethereum-bridge
       }

      function __callback(bytes32 myid, string result) {
                 if (msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()) throw;
                 weathercondition=result;
     }
     function update(string to,string datetime) payable returns(bool sufficient) {
               oraclize_query("URL", strConcat("json(http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q='", to ,"'&mode=json&APPID=d2e8279188c8649c17540f798c9cc972).list[?(@.dt_txt='", datetime, "')].weather[0].main"));
              return true;
       }
}
```

The following is the index.html file :-

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
        <title>Sample Truffle App</title>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
       <link href="./app.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
       <script src="./app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <h1>Airline</h1>
        <h2>Example Truffle Dapp</h2>
        <br>
        <h1>FORM</h1>
              <br><label for="from">From:</label><input type="text" id="from" placeholder="--Residing Place--"></input>
              <br><label for="to">To:</label><input type="text" id="to" placeholder="--Travelling Place--"></input>
              <br><label for="persons">No. of Persons:</label><input type="text" id="persons" placeholder="--No. of Persons--"></input>
              <br><label for="date">Travel Date:</label><input type="text" id="date" placeholder="--Date of travel yyyy-MM-dd--"></input>
              <br><label for="time">Destination Time:</label><input type="text" id="time" placeholder="--HH:mm:ss--"></input>
              <br><br><button id="send" onclick="sendRequest()">Generate Quote</button> 
             <br><br>
 </body>
 </html>
```

The following is the app.js file.

```
    var accounts;
    var account;

    function getTransactionReceiptMined(){

              web3.eth.getTransactionReceiptMined = function (txnHash, interval) {
                       var transactionReceiptAsync;
                       interval = interval ? interval : 500;
                       transactionReceiptAsync = function(txnHash, resolve, reject) {
                       try {
                                   var receipt = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txnHash);
                                  if (receipt == null) {
                                               setTimeout(function () {
                                                 transactionReceiptAsync(txnHash, resolve, reject);
                                                }, interval);
                                  } else {
                                                 resolve(receipt);
                                   }
                    } catch(e) {
                           reject(e);
                    }
     };

    if (Array.isArray(txnHash)) {
                  var promises = [];
                  txnHash.forEach(function (oneTxHash) {
                               promises.push(web3.eth.getTransactionReceiptMined(oneTxHash, interval));
                   });
                      return Promise.all(promises);
                   } else {
                              return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                                       transactionReceiptAsync(txnHash, resolve, reject);
                            });
                  }
     };

 }

 function sendRequest() {
       var weatherapicall = WeatherApiCall.deployed();
       var fromdata = document.getElementById("from").value;
       var to = document.getElementById("to").value;
       var persons = parseInt(document.getElementById("persons").value);
       var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
       var time = document.getElementById("time").value;
       //verifying at javascript console
        console.log(fromdata);
        console.log(to);
        console.log(persons);
        console.log(date);
        console.log(time);
        var timeperiod;     
        if ((time >= '00:00:00') && (time < '03:00:00')) {
                    timeperiod = '00:00:00';
        } else if ((time >= '03:00:00') && (time < '06:00:00')) {
                    timeperiod = '03:00:00';
        } else if ((time >= '06:00:00') && (time < '09:00:00')) {
                    timeperiod = '06:00:00';
        } else if ((time >= '09:00:00') && (time < '12:00:00')) {
                    timeperiod = '09:00:00';
        } else if ((time >= '12:00:00') && (time < '15:00:00')) {
                   timeperiod = '12:00:00';
        } else if ((time >= '15:00:00') && (time < '18:00:00')) {
                  timeperiod = '15:00:00';
        } else if ((time >= '18:00:00') && (time < '21:00:00')) {
                  timeperiod = '18:00:00';
       } else if ((time >= '21:00:00') && (time < '24:00:00')) {
                  timeperiod = '21:00:00';
       }
      datetime = date + ' ' + timeperiod;
      console.log(datetime);    
      WeatherApiCall.deployed().update(to ,datetime, {from: account}).then(function(txn) {
                   console.log("Testing");
                   console.log("transaction submited", txn);
                   return getTransactionReceiptMined(txn); // wait for mined result    
      })
      .then(function(receipt) {
                   console.log("transaction mined", receipt);
      })
     .catch(function(e) {
                   console.log(e);     
     });
 };
  window.onload = function() {
           web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err, accs) {
           if (err != null) {
                  alert("There was an error fetching your accounts.");
                  return;
           }
           if (accs.length == 0) {
                  alert("Couldn't get any accounts! Make sure your Ethereum client is configured correctly.");
                  return;
           }
           accounts = accs;
           account = accounts[0];         
         });
 }
```

I have used 'testrpc' as client.

I have used ethereum-bridge for oraclize.

[image]

Based on the OAR address i have updated my contract OAR address.

I have used the following commands to check the functions in solidity contract.
[image]

The contract.update function call the url given in the oraclizequery and fetch the result.It can be shown in the terminal window for ethereum-bridge.
In the ethereum-bridge terminal window,contract.update function call creates a query and fetches the result based on dynamic input.
[image]

I have tried the dapp in my localhost:8080.
[image]

From the output i have infered that the transaction is submitted correctly but won't get mined.While checking in my ethereum-bridge terminal no query is created on clicking the button 'Generate Quote'.

I have added the code in github account for your reference.
[Github Reference Link](https://github.com/mariam-crissi/Flightdapp)